# Problem with rigid body joint

Tags: game-engine, constraints

I have two meshes and I need they remain together while they move but being different meshes, so Ctrl+J is not the solution. I've tried to put a rigid body joint but when I activate it the two pieces get apart.

I need the two pieces remain in this position

[image: I need the two pieces remain in this position]

When I press the up key this is what happen

[image: When I press the up key this is what happen]

Here is the file: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/29210

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried to lock everything but then I coludn't move the objects. The solution is to put an Always sensor and a Parent actuator in the game logic.

Answer (score 3):

[Rigid body joints constraints](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Constraints/Relationship/Rigid_Body_Joint) intented use is for situations like:

[image]
<sup>Animation created from the blend file linked in the docs</sup>

Note the collision bounds are set to box and the joint itself doesn't have a collision bound.

Comparing your file you have collision bound set to capsule which should be mesh:

[image]

Setting it to triangle mesh would at least avoid that it is blown away when you switch on the physics.

[image]

In case you only want to parent both objects you wouldn't need the constraints:

First select the child object then the parent <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>P</kbd> will open this popup.

[image]

To have the influence of parenting animated you could consider to use a [ChildOf constrained](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Constraints/Relationship/Child_Of).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried establishing a child parent relationship between the two (cf http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Objects/Groups_and_Parenting)?

ns