# How to rotate object around another with rigid body constraint in BGE?

Tags: game-engine, rigid-body-simulation

I want to use rigid body constraint to rotate the camera around a cube accordingly to the angular velocity of the cube(all of that in the BGE).

1)Is it necessary for both objects to be rigid? For one? For none?

2)From this [question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10438/problem-with-rigid-body-joint) I understood that what I want is a slider constraint but I want the camera to be affected by the rotation of the cube and the cube to be unaffected by anything the camera does.If it is possible how do I fill the empty boxes in the constraint and does it matter which object will "own" the constraint?

3)Any good video tutorial for that purpose(the pivot) will be appreciated.